# Is Civi Mobile and Tablet Ready

Tags: mobile

Can Civi be accessed via the iPhone or Android phones and what about on the iPad or other tablets?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to CiviMobile and Cividroid, the full CiviCRM app works reasonably well on a tablet, particularly for public-facing pages - and work is underway to make it fully responsive.  You can give it a try from a tablet at http://demo.civicrm.org and see if it meets your current needs.

Answer (score 4):

There is a beta Android app that a Google Summer of Code student did - Cividroid - see [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36037.25;wap2).

And there is [CiviMobile](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobile), a very basic mobile version written in jquery I believe for a mobile browser that needs some more work.

Answer (score 0):

We've had to do some work to make it better on mobile, see https://donate.creativecommons.org/ for example. We're continuing to make it easier to make a donation on mobile.

Comment: unclear how this Answer helps. it just seems to say 'we did something' without actually offering any help, solution, sharing of code, etc